# Leaflet map not loading in tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, tabs

My leaflet map not loading properly in bootstrap tab panel, I checked that my leaflet map opened perfectly in active tab class but those tabs that not have active class my map show properly like map show perfectly in this tab

```
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active animated bounceInRight" id="mv">
  <div class="row pv-50 bordr-top">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id='mapi'></div>
    </div>
</div> </div>
```

But not showing properly in this tab

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane animated bounceInRight" id="mv">
 <div class="row pv-50 bordr-top">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id='mapi'></div>
    </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to check with firebug ? It seems you are missing some important class

Comment: Yes i try but not know why its happen, I just found that if i place active class in map tab panel div it load perfectly but if i remove active class from tab panel div my map not load perfect.

Comment: it is hard to say anything without looking the code, Is there any chance you can show me on jsfiddler ,